# How to use a KTable as reference data to update a KStream?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka topic that contains data in Json:

```
{"id": "A", "country": "France"}
{"id": "B", "currency": "£"}
```

And I want to normalize the content with something like a "reference table":

```
country ( "France" ) -> "FR"
currency ( "£" ) -> "GBP"
```

in order to output:

```
{"id": "A", "country": "FR"}
{"id": "B", "currency": "GBP"}
```

I think this is a typical use case of using a `KTable` to store the reference data. But I am a little bit stuck on the implementation.

**Current state**

***Ingesting the reference data***

Dedicated topic created on Kafka : `poc-mapping-in`

Topic feeded with sample Json Data :

```
{"mapping":"ccy",     "from":"£",      "to":"GBP"}
{"mapping":"country", "from":"France", "to":"FR"}
```

Data ingested in `KTable` after rework on the key and value :

```
         KStream<String, String> mappingStream = builder
                .stream("poc-mapping-in",consumed)
                .map(
                     (key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(
                         value.get("mapping")+"#"+value.get("from"), 
                         value.get("to").asText())
         );

         KGroupedStream<String, String> mappingGroupedStream = mappingStream.groupByKey(
                 Serialized.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String() ));


         KTable<String,String> mappingTable = mappingGroupedStream.aggregate(
                () -> "", //initializer 
                (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> newValue, // adder 
                Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("ReferenceStore")
                    .withValueSerde(Serdes.String())
                    .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                );

           // Testing
           mappingTable.toStream().to("poc-mapping-in-content", 
                Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
```

And in the topic `poc-mapping-in-content`, I get these lines:

```
"currency"#"£"      GBP
"country"#"France"  FR
```

That looks like what I expected. The double-quotes are weird, but it does not block me to go further.

And the data is/should be stored in a local store called `ReferenceStore`.

***Ingesting the business flow***

Topic created on Kafka : `poc-raw-events`

Topic feeded with sample Json Data :

```
{"id": "A", "country": "France"}
{"id": "B", "currency": "£"}
```

Data ingested in `KStream`:

```
  final Consumed<String, JsonNode> consumed = Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde);
  KStream<String, JsonNode> businessData = builder.stream("poc-raw-events", consumed);
```

From here I do not know what to do. Technically, I know how to update an attribute in my JsonNode. So I tried to loop on the `KStream` with `foreach`, this way:

```
    businessData.foreach(new ForeachAction<String, JsonNode>()  {
        public void apply(String k, JsonNode v) {
            System.out.println(k+ " : " +v);
                    if (v==null) {System.out.println("NULL detected"); return;}
            Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = v.fields();
            int i=0;
            while (fields.hasNext()) {
                i++;
                Entry<String, JsonNode> next = fields.next();
                System.out.println(k+ " field #"+i+" : " +next.getKey() + " -- " + next.getValue());

                String key = next.getKey() + "#" + next.getValue());
//              ((ObjectNode) v).put(next.getKey(), "  WHAT HERE ??? ");

            }

        }
    });
```

And my idea was to replace the `"  WHAT HERE ??? "` in the last line with the data present in the reference KTable. But how ???

- I did not find something like a `.findByKey()` on a KTable.
- I do not know how to access the `ReferenceStore` local store, because the way to access it is something like `myKafkaStream.store(...)` and at this moment `myKafkaStream` is not started yet, neither it is even built.

Another way I thought about was to use the KStream leftJoin KTable capability. But I read somewhere (I did not bookmark...) that to do that, we should use the same key in both KTables. But in my case, on the Json side, I do not work on the key to join, but on a simple attribute.

How would you implement this?

Comment: I think you are looking for a `stream.join(table)`: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#joining -- also check out: https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/

Comment: Thank you Matthias. I solved the issue with a `transform(.... , "ReferenceStore")`. I will try to do it with a `leftJoin` which is probably a more elegant way.

Answer (score 4):

Since you using reference data, I think what you want to consider using is a `GlobalKTable`.  A `GlobalKTable` is completely replicated per `KafkaStreams` instance and was created explicitly for holding reference data for a use case as you have above.

What's unique about KStream-GlobalKTable joins is you can use the `KeyValue` of the stream to map to the key of the `GlobalKTable`.  So as long as you can pull the attribute out of your `JsonNode`, you should be able to join with the appropriate record in the `GlobalKTable.`

Comment: Thank you bbejeck. I am simply coding a poc, where I do not need to use a GlobalKTable. But yes, it will make sense to use that when we will code "for real".  In fact my issue was that I did not notice that I could pass the local store as a parameter when I call a .transform().

Comment: So here, after `final Consumed<String, JsonNode> consumed = Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde);`, I coded this transform :       `KStream<String, JsonNode> outputStream = consumed.transform(new TransformerSupplier<String,JsonNode,KeyValue<String,JsonNode>>() { ... }, "ReferenceStore");`....and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If referenceKTable has a key that matches data.getAltKey()

```
streamToMap.selectKey((originalKey, data) -> data.getAltKey()).leftJoin(referenceKTable, valueJoiner)
```

can accomplish that. The implementation of valueJoiner (or a lambda) must combine the two inputs.